# Can you use js object destructuring but modify some of the values before assigning to the new object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I have the following code that receives movie data from an api. Now I want to create a new object from the returned json file but only containing a subset of the properties while also modifying some of the existing property values before assigning them to the new object, I am currently doing this the long way but is there a way I can achieve this result using javascript/typescript object destructuring syntax?

I want to use some of the existing properties like `title` and `overview` but want to change the `poster_path` property value (I set these values in the first two lines after the if statement). Can I achieve the same result in a more concise/efficient way?

```
movieCollection.results.forEach(
      (movie: {
        poster_path: string,
        backdrop_path: string,
        title: string,
        overview: string,
        release_date: string,
        vote_average: number,
        vote_count: number,
        genre_ids: number[],
      }) => {

        if (movie.backdrop_path) {

          //create paths for pictures
          let poster_path = this.secureBaseURL + this.posterSizes[4] + movie.poster_path;
          let backdrop_path = this.secureBaseURL + this.posterSizes[5] + movie.backdrop_path;

          //create array object
          movieArray.push({
            poster_path: poster_path,
            backdrop_path: backdrop_path,
            title: movie.title,
            overview: movie.overview,
            release_date: movie.release_date,
            vote_average: movie.vote_average,
            vote_count: movie.vote_count,
            genre_ids: movie.genre_ids,
            styles: {},
          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to achieve the same result efficiently. It allows an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected; here are your objects in the new array.

```js
movieCollection.results.forEach(
  (movie: {
    poster_path: string,
    backdrop_path: string,
    title: string,
    overview: string,
    release_date: string,
    vote_average: number,
    vote_count: number,
    genre_ids: number[],
  }) => {
    if (movie.backdrop_path) {
      //create array object
      movieArray.push({
        ...movie, // keep the unchanged properties
        poster_path: this.secureBaseURL + this.posterSizes[4] + movie.poster_path,
        backdrop_path: this.secureBaseURL + this.posterSizes[5] + movie.backdrop_path, // override these two properties as needed
        styles: {},
      });
    }
  });
```

However, I noticed that, seems what you want to do here is to change objects in an array and keep the updated result in another array? Then actually, you can use [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to refactor your code more concisely.

```js
const movieArray = movieCollection.results
  .filter((t) => !!t.backdrop_path) // filter by backdrop_path property
  .map(
    (movie) => ({
      ...movie, // keep the unchanged properties
      poster_path: this.secureBaseURL + this.posterSizes[4] + movie.poster_path,
      backdrop_path: this.secureBaseURL + this.posterSizes[5] + movie.backdrop_path,
      styles: {},
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you but is there a way I could only use some of the properties and not have all the unchanged properties in the new array (that is why I created the new array - to get rid of the ones I don't need. I considered using spread syntax but I don't want all the remaining properties).

Comment: @PiwiTheKiwi I see, then I think you should use the second approach, but in the map function body, we can return a new object that contains all the necessary properties you need. Although that may need a few more lines, it's inevitable as we need to customize the properties. (From your question, I see all properties are used in the new array, so I assumed that Spread syntax would suit you)